# If i want to write a prolog predicate to compare two periods (dates) and see if the two periods overlap ....for example :

Tags: date, prolog, compare, overlap, predicate

d) overlapPeriod/2

?- overlapPeriod(period(2010-8-12,2011-8-12),period(2010-9-12,2011-9-18)).

true.

?- overlapPeriod(period(2010-8-12,2011-8-12),period(2011-9-12,2011-9-18)).

false.

Comment: Okay. What is the exact problem that prevents you from doing that? Show your attempts at finding a solution!. Also, take a look at [time and date predicates](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=datimepreds). (P.S. Not structured the same as JSR-310, aka [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) it would be interesting to compare)

Comment: What have you tried so far?